# Set up deployment to app service using personal access token

Tags: azure-web-app-service, kudu

I've been given a personal access token (full access) which allows me to connect to a private Azure git repo within an Azure devops account from another subscription.  Connecting to that repo locally using git is working fine.

I would like to set this up as a CI/CD deployment source for my app service but have been unable to find out how to do this.  I tried Azure CLI:

```
az webapp deployment source config ... --repo-url https://anything:{pat}@dev.azure.com/Company/Project/_git/Reponame
```

This fails with a 500 error.

So I tried calling the [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/updatesourcecontrol) directly but that also fails with the 500 error so not an Azure CLI issue.

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction,
Thanks for the help, much appreciated

Comment: Did you try configuring CI/CD via "Deployment Center" blade of the WebApp?See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-continuous-deployment#enable-continuous-deployment

Comment: I believe that would only help if it was my devops account, not from another subscription?

Comment: The PAT works if I create an external manual deployment (push/sync) from the portal, just need this to work for CI/CD deployments.